# fabricJS - SVG parameters with toSVG

Tags: fabricjs

According to [this link](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGParamPrimer/), it is possible to modify a SVG, depending on the parameters included in the URL used to access this SVG.

Is it possible to do so using the `toSVG()` method ?

Let's say I create a basic canvas with a few elements. Once I'm done, I export and save the result of my `canvas.toSVG()` on AWS.

I get [this image](https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/balibart-s3/Products/5c053e6b535d0d1d2ccc1b2e/Mockups/front_svg.svg)

Is it possible to modify the way `toSVG()` behaves, so that adding `?color=red` at the end of the URL would make my tshirt red ?

I tried using the example from [the documentation](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html), using `replace()` on my canvas objects, but this generates empty SVGs.

Comment: Haven't you asked the same question with a little bit different wording a couple days ago?

Comment: Please see [duplicate of unanswered question by the same user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341107/closed-question-as-duplicate-of-unanswered-question-by-same-user)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fabricjs - Dynamic SVG with toSVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598681/fabricjs-dynamic-svg-with-tosvg)

Comment: The tshirt is a path.. you can get that path before making `toSVG` method and change the `fill` color

Comment: @MariusTurcu I know, but my point is precisely not to do it that way : I'd like to be able to change the color directly on the SVG, not on my canvas.